# Download file and move it (Android)

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm implementing a database update in my program. I got my sqlite3 database running and I'm able to check for updates, but my question is: How do I download a file from the web (the new database) and move it to the correct folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This page](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) has some good code for doing exactly that.

Also to get the path of where the database "should" go, you can use some code like this :

```
getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getPath();
```

Comment: Thanks but the problem of downloading the file still persists, how can I do it?

Comment: You say from the web, I imagine that's http ? There are a lot of tutorials to do that. For example, check out this : http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-download-fileimage-url-your-device

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this for a long time but ended up writing a synchronize script instead. I was working in xcode for iOS but I think it's the same principle.

I think the best solution is copy the embedded database to a non readonly location and synchronize what needs to be done.